# how to register all classes of a particular interface using .net core default service container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In unity I can register all types of an interface from an assembly using this way.

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

        container.RegisterTypes(
            AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().
                Where(
                    type =>
                        typeof (IRunAtInit).IsAssignableFrom(type),
            WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
            WithName.TypeName);

              }
```

Is it possible to implement it .net core  like this way using its own default service container ?

Answer (score 7):

Try use `Scrutor` extension: https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor

```cs
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<IRunAtInit>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IRunAtInit>())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithTransientLifetime());
```